# I am working in an ecommerce project using react.I am not able to fetch products from backend using the axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Below are the files as server.js , HomeScreen.js, pacKAGE.JSON and App.js file.
Not able to see anything in this path too: http://localhost:5000/api/products
Getting the error as "Cannot GET /api/products.
localhost:5000 is running fine.
Below are the files as server.js , HomeScreen.js, pacKAGE.JSON and App.js file.
Not able to see anything in this path too: http://localhost:5000/api/products
Getting the error as "Cannot GET /api/products.
Below are the files as server.js , HomeScreen.js, pacKAGE.JSON and App.js file.
Not able to see anything in this path too: http://localhost:5000/api/products
Getting the error as "Cannot GET /api/products.
Below are the files as server.js , HomeScreen.js, pacKAGE.JSON and App.js file.
Not able to see anything in this path too: http://localhost:5000/api/products
Getting the error as "Cannot GET /api/products.
Below are the files as server.js , HomeScreen.js, pacKAGE.JSON and App.js file.
Not able to see anything in this path too: http://localhost:5000/api/products
Getting the error as "Cannot GET /api/products.

Server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const products = require("./data/products");
const cors = require("cors");


const app = express()

app.use(cors());
app.get("/", (req, res) => {

    res.send("API is running...")
})

app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
    const product = products.find(p => p._id === req.params.id)
    res.json(product)
})

app.listen(5000, () => {

    console.log("Server running on port 5000")
})
```

HomeScreen.js file

```
 import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
 import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap"
 import Product from "../components/Product"
 import axios from "axios"


    const HomeScreen = () => {

const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hello")
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const {
            data
        } = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products')
        console.log(data);

        setProducts(data);
    }
    fetchProducts()
}, [])

return (
    <>
     <h1>Latest Products</h1>
     <Row>
           {products.map((product) => (

               <Col key = {product._id} sm = {12} md = {6} lg = {4} xl = {3}>
               <Product product = {product} />
               </Col>
           )


           )}
     </Row>
    </>
    )
   }

  export default HomeScreen
```

package.json file(frontend)

```
{
 "name": "frontend",
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.1",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.5.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
 },
 "scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
```

App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductScreen from "./screens/ProductScreen";


 const App = () =>  {
 return (
 <Router>
 <Header />
 <main className = "py-3">
  <Container>
  <Route path = "/" component = {HomeScreen} exact />
  <Route path = "/product/:id" component = {ProductScreen} />
  </Container>

 </main>
 <Footer/>
 </ Router>
 )
 }

export default App;
```

Comment: Just add a route for it. e.g. `app.get("/api/products", (req,res) => {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
    products.find({id:req.params.id}).exec(function(err, product) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          const product = res.json(product);
      }
  })
});
```

Comment: After adding the above lines in server.js ,it is throwing an error as :Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: products.map is not a function ...

Comment: app.get("/api/products", async (req,res) => {
       try { 
       const product =  products.find();
       res.json(product);
     console.log(product);
  } catch(e) {
    res.json(e);
    console.log("error found") 
 }
})

     app.get("/api/products/:id", (req,res) => {
     const product = products.find(p => p._id === req.params.id)
    res.json(product)
    })

Comment: it has been solved...i was missing one route and on adding it...it worked

Comment: app.get("/api/products",  (req,res)=> {

    res.json(products)
})

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a get route for "/api/products". If "products.find" return a promise and it should be handled.

```
app.get("/api/products", async (req,res) => {
    try { 
     const product = await products.find();
     res.json(product);
  } catch(e) {
    //handle the error here  
 }
})
```

Comment: I see, i assumed that the "products.find" is doing a database call.

Comment: Looking at OP's code `const products = require("./data/products");`, I actually doubt that `products.find();` is a an asynchronous operation tbh. Looks like a regular `find` against an array of objects. I don't think you need that `await` there.

Comment: that's right, that's why i added if "products.find" returns a promise it should be handled.